# Assertion Error while training using PyTorch lightning module on Microsoft FarmVibes crop segmentation model

Tags: conv-neural-network, raster, image-segmentation, torch, pytorch-lightning

First we initialized a dataset for pytorch to train upon it has similar functions like train dataloader, val dataloader, split_roi,etc.
Next we initialized our model with FPN, adam optimizer, LR scheduler, loss metrics, and functions like training step, validation step.
Finally with help of pytorch-lightning trainer we initialized our training on the data using segmentation model.

````
data = CropSegDataModule(
    ndvi_rasters,
    cdl_rasters,
    ndvi_stack_bands=NDVI_STACK_BANDS,
    img_size=(CHIP_SIZE, CHIP_SIZE),
    epoch_size=EPOCH_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    num_workers=NUM_WORKERS,
    positive_indices=constants.CROP_INDICES,
    val_ratio=VAL_RATIO
)
data.setup()

model = SegmentationModel(lr=LR, 
                        weight_decay=WD, 
                        in_channels=NDVI_STACK_BANDS,
                        num_epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                        classes=1,
                        )
# Default checkpoint callback will save a checkpoint at the end of every epoch
callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint()]

# Change to gpus=0 to run on CPU
trainer = Trainer(max_epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, callbacks=callbacks, default_root_dir=ROOT_DIR, gpus = 0)
trainer.fit(model, data)

```

Converting CDLMask CRS from EPSG:5070 to EPSG:32611
Converting CDLMask resolution from 30.0 to 10.0

  | Name          | Type              | Params
----------------------------------------------------
0 | model         | FPN               | 23.3 M
1 | loss          | BCEWithLogitsLoss | 0     
2 | train_metrics | MetricCollection  | 0     
3 | val_metrics   | MetricCollection  | 0     
----------------------------------------------------
23.3 M    Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
23.3 M    Total params
93.048    Total estimated model params size (MB)


AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_189332/4116084536.py in <module>
----> 1 trainer.fit(model, data)

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    694         """
    695         self.strategy.model = model
--> 696         self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    697             self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    698         )

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _call_and_handle_interrupt(self, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    648                 return self.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=self, **kwargs)
    649             else:
--> 650                 return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    651         # TODO(awaelchli): Unify both exceptions below, where `KeyboardError` doesn't re-raise
    652         except KeyboardInterrupt as exception:

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    733             ckpt_path, model_provided=True, model_connected=self.lightning_module is not None
    734         )
--> 735         results = self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
    736 
    737         assert self.state.stopped

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run(self, model, ckpt_path)
   1164         self._checkpoint_connector.resume_end()
   1165 
-> 1166         results = self._run_stage()
   1167 
   1168         log.detail(f"{self.__class__.__name__}: trainer tearing down")

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_stage(self)
   1250         if self.predicting:
   1251             return self._run_predict()
-> 1252         return self._run_train()
   1253 
   1254     def _pre_training_routine(self):

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_train(self)
   1272 
   1273         with isolate_rng():
-> 1274             self._run_sanity_check()
   1275 
   1276         # enable train mode

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_sanity_check(self)
   1341             # run eval step
   1342             with torch.no_grad():
-> 1343                 val_loop.run()
   1344 
   1345             self._call_callback_hooks("on_sanity_check_end")

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/loop.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    198             try:
    199                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 200                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    201                 self.on_advance_end()
    202                 self._restarting = False

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/dataloader/evaluation_loop.py in advance(self, *args, **kwargs)
    153         if self.num_dataloaders > 1:
    154             kwargs["dataloader_idx"] = dataloader_idx
--> 155         dl_outputs = self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher, dl_max_batches, kwargs)
    156 
    157         # store batch level output per dataloader

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/loop.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    198             try:
    199                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 200                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    201                 self.on_advance_end()
    202                 self._restarting = False

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/evaluation_epoch_loop.py in advance(self, data_fetcher, dl_max_batches, kwargs)
    141 
    142         # lightning module methods
--> 143         output = self._evaluation_step(**kwargs)
    144         output = self._evaluation_step_end(output)
    145 

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/evaluation_epoch_loop.py in _evaluation_step(self, **kwargs)
    238         """
    239         hook_name = "test_step" if self.trainer.testing else "validation_step"
--> 240         output = self.trainer._call_strategy_hook(hook_name, *kwargs.values())
    241 
    242         return output

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _call_strategy_hook(self, hook_name, *args, **kwargs)
   1702 
   1703         with self.profiler.profile(f"[Strategy]{self.strategy.__class__.__name__}.{hook_name}"):
-> 1704             output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   1705 
   1706         # restore current_fx when nested context

~/miniconda3/envs/crop-seg/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py in validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs)
    368         with self.precision_plugin.val_step_context():
    369             assert isinstance(self.model, ValidationStep)
--> 370             return self.model.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
    371 
    372     def test_step(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:

~/farmvibes-ai/notebooks/crop_segmentation/notebook_lib/models.py in validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx)
     95 
     96     def validation_step(self, batch: Dict[str, Any], batch_idx: int) -> Dict[str, Any]:
---> 97         return self._shared_step(batch, batch_idx)
     98 
     99     def validation_step_end(self, outputs: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:

~/farmvibes-ai/notebooks/crop_segmentation/notebook_lib/models.py in _shared_step(self, batch, batch_idx)
     76         pred = self(batch["image"])
     77         for t in pred, batch["mask"]:
---> 78             assert torch.all(torch.isfinite(t))
     79         loss = self.loss(pred, batch["mask"])
     80 

AssertionError: 

# trainer.fit(model, data)
While performing the above operation it unexpectedly stopped at sanity check resulting with some assertion error. What should be done in order to train the model?
````